# Sum for columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want sum for columns. But the columns is each 3 columns, E.g. I want sum the column 4, column 7, column 10, ... column 48.

I'm use the function `WorksheetFunction.Sum`

```
For j = 1 To 54
    For i = 3 To 48 Step 3
        Cells(4 + j, 54) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(4 + j, i + 1))
    Next i
Next j
```

But the result in every row is 0. How do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following could work:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum As Double
For j = 1 To 54
    sum = 0 ' reset the sum for each iteration of the outer loop
    For i = 3 To 48 Step 3
        sum = sum + Cells(4 + j, i + 1).Value
    Next i
    Cells(4 + j, 54).Value = sum
Next j
```

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub summate()
    
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    For i = 7 To 49 Step 3
        s = s & ",RC" & i
    Next
    Range("BB5:BB58").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC4" & s & ")"

End Sub
```